# QueryException in Hibernate because of apostrophe

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, apostrophe

Here its my Query

```
SQL_QUERY="SELECT review.comment FROM ReviewDO review WHERE title='"+titleName+"'";
```

By using title am trying to get its description.

For **Example** if `tileName="Worth for money";` (without apostrophe) the query will be:

```
SQL_QUERY="SELECT review.comment FROM ReviewDO review WHERE title='Worth for money';
```

am getting the output.

but if `titleName="Can't beat the product";`(with apostrophe)

```
SQL_QUERY="SELECT review.comment FROM ReviewDO review WHERE title='Can't beat the product';
```

am getting **org.hibernate.QueryException:expecting ''',found 'EOF'**

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use placeholders. It will also help in preventing SQL injections:

```
 Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  String query = "SELECT review.comment FROM ReviewDO review WHERE title=:title";
  List<ReviewComment> reviewComments = ses.createQuery(query)
  .setParameter("title", "Can't beat the product")
  .list();
  ses.close();
```

And if you are sure that your query will give only one record then instead of using list()  use uniqueResult() method of Query interface.

For more details see the documentation of Query interface [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html)

Comment: how do I use that using Criteria?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PreparedStatement` instead of simple query and let `PreparedStatement` handles apostrophe and other special characters for you. Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) Oracle's documentation.

Second way is to use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) library. Refer the doc.

Comment: StringEscapeUtils is nice option

Comment: PreparedStatement is not option when we are using hibernate. It is abstracted by Hibernate

Comment: Second way is to use StringEscapeUtils library. Refer the doc. 
It will not work for single quotes specifically to sql query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL_QUERY="SELECT review.comment FROM ReviewDO review WHERE title='Can't beat the product';
    
You can simple do it by refer below code. 
just add SQL_QUERY.replace("'", "''"); As per SQL query side if any string contain ( ' ) in string then while running just add ''.
    
Ex: "SELECT review.comment FROM ReviewDO review WHERE title='Can''t beat the product';
```